Mapping with IdClass rising a reflection exception
Assuming the following entities
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERSS_SERVERS")
@IdClass(UserssServersID.class)
public class UserssServers implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1516544321200552891L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_USERSS_SERVERS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_USERSS_SERVERS", sequenceName = "SEQ_USERSS_SERVERS", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "USERSS_SERVERS_ID")
    private Long id;
 
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVER_ID", referencedColumnName = "SERVER_ID", nullable = true)
    private Server server;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID",referencedColumnName = "USER_ID", nullable = true)
    private User user;


and

@Entity
@Table(name = "serverss")
public class Server extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -634761707473655857L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_SERVERS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_SERVERS", sequenceName = "SEQ_SERVERS", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "SERVER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SERVER_NAME", length = 256, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "SERVER_DESCRIPTION", length = 256, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "SERVER_IP", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String ip;

with

public class UserssServersID implements Serializable {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 25698544213456L;

     Long id;
     User user;
     Server server;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }
    public void setServer(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
     public UserssServersID() { 
    }


having

@Entity
@Table(name = "userss")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9171709207204938565L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_USERS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_USERS", sequenceName = "SEQ_USERS", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVE_USERSS_SERVERS_ID", 
referencedColumnName="USERSS_SERVERS_ID", nullable = true)
    private UserssServers activeServerConfig;

when trying to persist data somehow the IdClass throws the following
    ... 204 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.bnpp.pf.diligense.entity.classid.UserssServersID.id to java.lang.Long
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:425) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    ... 231 common frames omitted

the persistence logic is like below :
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void setServerInformation(ServerInformationRequest serverInformation) {
        User user = getCurrentUser();

        Server server = serverRepository.findByIpAndPort(serverInformation.getServerIp(), serverInformation.getServerPort());
        if (server == null) {
            throw new BusinessException(UNIX_SERVER_NOT_FOUND.getMessage(), UNIX_SERVER_NOT_FOUND.getCode());
        }

        UserssServers userssServers = userssServersService.findByIpAndPort(serverInformation.getServerIp(), serverInformation.getServerPort(), user.getId());
        if (userssServers != null) {
            informationRequestMapper.updateEntity(userssServers, serverInformation);
            userssServers.setPassword(serverInformation.getPassword() == null ? userssServers.getPassword() : serverInformation.getPassword());
            userssServers.setUpdateDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
        } else {
            userssServers = informationRequestMapper.modelToEntity(serverInformation);
            userssServers.setUser(user);
            userssServers.setCreationDate(OffsetDateTime.now());
            userssServers.setCreationUser(user);
            userssServers.setServer(server);
        }

        UserssServers savedUserssServers = userssServersService.saveServerInformation(userssServers);
        user.setActiveServerConfig(savedUserssServers);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

